# Tap Payment React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, payment, tap-payment

I'm trying to use tap payment in react native https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tap-payments/gosell-sdk-react-native. I got my secret keys for SDK.
I do everything the same as it is written in documentation. But after I click to my button and call method `RNGoSell.goSellSDK.startPayment(sdkConfigurations, handleResult);` I get error response `{"sdk_result": "FAILED", "trx_mode": "CHARGE"}`.

What can be problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to contact tap payment support(https://businesses.tap.company/) and ask them secrets. After it will work

Comment: I did that. They provided me with secret keys. But still same response. Did you solve it with secret keys ? If yes, then can you please guide me here ? @Exoriri

Comment: @AliRaza Sorry, can't remember that already.

Comment: Did you solve it or not ? @Exoriri ?

Comment: Yes. I wouldn't written an answer if I didn't. That is how I solved a problem two years ago. @AliRaza

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I am still facing this error, even after putting all the correct keys.